# Why is this conversion allowed?

Tags: c++

So I have this code(stolen from cplusplus.com):

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
  explicit B (const A& x) {}
  B& operator= (const A& x) {return *this;}
  operator A() {return A();}
};

void fn (B x) {}

int main ()
{
  A foo;
  B bar (foo);
  bar = foo;
  foo = bar;

//  fn (foo);  // not allowed for explicit ctor.
  fn (bar);  

  return 0;
}
```

So the conversion constructor can only be called explicitly and thereby `fn(foo);` is not allowed. This made me confused, because why can you do `B bar (foo);` if you cannot do `fn(foo);`, I mean doesn't fn(foo) also end up in initializing an object of type B to an object of type A, like in the statement `B bar (foo);`, so what are they both not generating an error? What is particularly explicit in `B bar (foo);` that is not explicit in the function call?

Comment: In `B bar (foo);` You are *explicit*ly telling the compiler to make you a `B`.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver but there is something that I do not really understand, so could you please take a look at the comment to Curious' answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `B bar(foo)` means that you are calling the constructor of `B` with foo as the argument, this is an `explicit` construction.  Whereas when you call `fn(foo)` the compiler tries to implicitly convert `foo` to match the function argument type, and this is an `implicit` conversion and is therefore not allowed since your convert constructor is marked `explicit`.

Comment: Thank you but when you say that the compiler tries to implicitly convert foo to match the function argument type, it sounds like this happens BEFORE the parameter is assigned the argument. Therefore, why would the the conversion constructor be called instead of the type-cast operator, I mean if it happens BEFORE that any object is being created, why does it call the constructor?

Comment: @user689574 The function arguments are not constructed till the function is called.  And when the function is called the arguments are constructed with the values that are passed to the function as arguments.  That's just how it works in C++.  Assignment happens on an already constructed object, and when the function is called the function parameters are constructed, so there is no room for assignment until the function body is run

Comment: "And when the function is called the arguments are constructed with the values that are passed to the function as arguments." The first time you said arguments, did you mean parameters or? Your comment helped me  but I am still not sure why fn(foo) cannot be called, I mean technically, if you called the function like `fn(foo)`, isn't the paramter x simply get assigned foo, like `B x = foo`? If so, I cannot see why this is not allowed since that is the exact same thing as `B bar (foo);` which is allowed. Please help me out here.

Comment: @user689574 Sorry for the late reply, yes, that is what happens, with two key differences from what you said.  1. `B x = foo` is a construction not an assignment.  And 2. calling a function requires an implicit conversion.  That's just the way the language works.  `B x{foo};` is an explicit conversion where as function argument construction requires an implicit conversion and so does `B x = foo`.  If you had called the function like `fn (B{foo})` then it would have worked, because here you are overriding the implicit conversion behavior with an explicit construction

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer all my questions!

Comment: Uh hold on, one last thing: If I then did `fn (B(foo));` in order to override the implicit conversion, will it still call the conversion constructor or a the copy-constructor since there then would be an argument of type B? Or what? This is actually the last thing, otherwise I think I finally got it all :)

Comment: So first it will call the convert constructor and then after that it will call either the move constructor for B or elide the move